# CSS Not Displaying, Using Python

Tags: python, html, css

The CSS is not displaying. I am using GoogleAppEngineLauncher for the project to create a simple form that displays the information entered. The script itself works just fine as I have it now, but the CSS is not being displayed and I don't know why.

In the console I have:

```
INFO     2016-09-09 21:39:26,961 module.py:809] default: "GET /assets/custom/css/fsp.css HTTP/1.1" 404 154
```

And a portion of the python script:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    page_head = '''
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/custom/css/fsp.css">
    <title>Audi Test Drive Request</title>
    </head>
    '''
```

Any ideas?

I think it's because I'm using GoogleAppEngineLauncher and it's localhost:9080 and that might be the reason that it's not finding it correctly, if that's the problem, but I don't have a solution at the moment.

Comment: It literally says it couldn't find the CSS file at the location you specified in the console log... `default: "GET /assets/custom/css/fsp.css HTTP/1.1" 404`. A 404 HTTP return code means, `not found`. Fix the file location/path and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Does `assets/custom/css/fsp.css` exist? If you go to `yoursite.com/assets/custom/css/fsp.css` do you see the CSS you expect?

Comment: http://localhost:9080/assets doesn't even exist, even though its in the same directory. It must have something to do with GoogleAppEngineLauncher itself? It displays the HTML but it's not accessing the CSS because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Figured it out. It's because the CSS was not declared in the app.yaml file itself.